# Full URL for one specific page content only in Typo3 while the rest follows the base URL constant

Tags: url, typoscript, radix, typo3-4.5

I am managing an association's site using typo 3 version 4.5.30. The site has the config setup for [baseURL] = http://www.afj-japon.org/ in its template.
Everything works fine, but I need ONE page only to have the URLs written in full in the code.
Right now the page code indicates
 
and the URLs are written in full for the redirections to other pages, but as  for the images.
I need to have the code to actually be as 
How can I set this to affect only this one page and not the whole site ?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards,
Gilles

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question right you want to have absolute URLs on one certain page, right?

TYPO3 comes with a setting called config.absRefPrefix.
If said one page has no child-pages you can set up an extension template on that page and have this line in there:
config.absRefPrefix = http://www.afj-japon.org/

If the page has child-pages underneath it, you will have to use a condition in the ID of that page.

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = PAGE-UID]
config.absRefPrefix = http://www.afj-japon.org/
[global]
```

Mind that every condition has to be evaluated prior to caching so having a lot of conditions might make your website slower.